# Why system time to time kill app which on foreground without exception?

Tags: android, kill

I just try to understand the reason of it. Our app is really stable and optimized, but time to time it just switch off during the work on foreground mode. User is using it, and it' just closed without any crash or ANR messages - really bad experience. What we already did:

- use UncaughtExceptionHandler and print logs to the disk for analyzing. Logs are empty, not information about crashes for these cases
- used Firebase crashlityc - is empty too
- checked app with help profiler and leakcanary - no leak, memory using ~200 Mb

A bit words about our app:

- clear arhitecture, Kotlin, MVVM, coroutines, dagger, retrofit, room, one single activity app
- app should work all time, infinitely. App is an interface for hardware terminal.
- the most part of fragments are stored into the backstack and reused again, it help to make screen opening faster after first fragment using. No leak with it, no fragment or viewModels duplicates
- we use glide for downloading and previewing user avatars. I'm afraid, that leaks could be a part of bitmaps or jpg. Profiler doesn't show it after 1-2 hours tests, but I didn't test it during for ex. one week
- possible app interruptions happen more often, when device is uncharged or just started (first 10-20 minutes after device start)
- the most part of clients has a bad WIFI connections
- we have ~10 modules, the most part of them are own canvas libs
- crashes happen in random moments...
- we also have ANR problem for some clients, but we added ANR watchdog, so soon we will know the reason of it.
- we have 50-60 singletons. I'm not sure, that is bad or good. The first plan was using much memory to make app faster.

For me it looks like a native crash or system kill, but how to repeat it? I still don't understand the real reason of it. If you faced with similar problem, please describe your experience, it could be helpful for us. Thx!

Comment: *app should work all time, infinitely* not possible

Comment: @Tim, "not possible" why?